# How to redirect the output from desktop-entry

Tags: linux, mono, io-redirection

I have a program called *prg.exe* written in C#. I want to run this program in mono with an argument (arg1) and redirect the output to a log file called *log.txt*.
If I open a terminal and enter the command:

```
mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > log.txt
```

everything works fine.
When the program is finished, the *log.txt* file is created, which contains any error.
Now I want to create a desktop entry called *prg.desktop*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My prg
Comment=some comment
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/openbox.xpm
Exec=mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > log.txt
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Categories=None;
```

If I run *prg.desktop*, the *log.txt* file is **not** created.
What do I need to do to create the log file?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I foud the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1339075/how-to-redirect-the-output-from-desktop-entry

```
Exec=sh -c "mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > log.txt"
```

Comment: Reasonable. Congrats :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to give the absolute path to txt file?
In many cases the file is usually created, just you can not see it.

something like :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My prg
Comment=some comment
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/openbox.xpm
Exec=mono --debug prg.exe arg1 > /home/op/Programe/Consola/log.txt
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Terminal=false
Categories=None;
```

Comment: The absolute path to txt file is:
/home/op/Programe/Consola/log.txt

Comment: @Viorel I meant in the `prg.desktop` file :)

Comment: In fact, the Exec line in the prg.desktop file is:  
Exec=mono --debug /home/op/Programe/Consola/Sonia_Cons.exe multiconect > /home/op/Programe/Consola/log.txt

Comment: I think "> /home/op/Programe/Consola/log.txt" is interpreted as another argument for prg.exe.

Comment: Just tried it. Log.txt works with full path and > redirection. Can you try giving the exact path to executable as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.  It still doesn't work for me.  I'll try harder.

Answer (score 0):

I found in another case that when you click a .desktop file to run it, the stdout
is gnome-shell, and the content is logged to /var/log/syslog on ubuntu. The file name maybe different on other OS.